# Environment specific urls in Spring Integration configuration file

Tags: spring-integration

I'm looking whether its possible to dynamically configure for different environments -

1. API KEY
2. gateway URL

---

```
<int:chain input-channel="reportInChannel" 
   output-channel="headerFilterChannel"> 
    <int:header-enricher>           
        <int:header name="Api-Key" value="B82853E8B"></int:header>      
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int-http:outbound-gateway  
                          url="https://shh.str1.tst.bl/ia-zadmin/rest/sign/v2/{signalId}"
                          http-method="GET"                
                          header-mapper="headerMapper" 
                          expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                          encode-uri="false" request-factory="sslFactory">             
                    <int-http:uri-variable name="signalId" expression="payload" />
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
    <int:object-to-string-transformer></int:object-to-string-transformer>
</int:chain>
```

Edit 1:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@ImportResource({"classpath:/common.xml","classpath:/so-on-config.xml"})
@EnableJms
@EnableSwagger2c
public class SpringIntegrationMQApplication {

private QueueConnectionFactory jmsConFactory;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringIntegrationMQApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public Docket api() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
      .select()                                  
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
      .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
      .build();                                           
}

 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }
```

}

The placeholders in my config xml are not substituted. Also I would like to  be able to use profiles [application-test.properties] etc. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use in the attributed a [Properties Placeholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors). So, your `B82853E8B` can be replaced with something like:

```
 <int:header name="Api-Key" value="${my.api.key}">
```

The `url` in the `<int-http:outbound-gateway`  can also be as a reference to some externally cofgigured property:

```
 url="${my.http.url}"
```

Comment: I couldn't correlate the spring docs with my project. Is the above solution possible with profiles? Scenario: Spring boot application with PropertySource annotation for application.properties [can i use profile?], ImportResource that has array of all config.xml files . @Bean new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() .. But the value in xml isn't replaced.

Comment: That `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` `@Bean` method has to be declared with `static` modifier.